# LARAVEL | Как обновить значение в промежуточной таблице

Tags: php, laravel, form, eloquent

Имеется таблица следующего типа:

```
Schema::create('items_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('item_id');
    $table->integer('option_id');
    $table->integer('sort')->nullable();
    $table->string('value')->nullable();
});
```

В форме идёт выборка данных опций:

```
<select name="options[]" multiple>
    @foreach ($options as $option)
        <option value="{{ $option->id }}">{{ $option->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

После обновления появляется поле для ввода:

```
<input type="text" name="option[{{ $option->id }}]" value="{{ $option->value }}">
```

Собственно сам вопрос, как записать значение в промежуточную таблицу если она уже была создана и **item** был присоединён к **option** а значение хотелось бы менять в ходе работы, а не при соединении.

Вот ссылка на первоисточник, всё предельно понятно, но как связать с последующим обновлением не совсем..
[ПЕРВОИСТОЧНИК](https://laravel.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=2257)

(используется связь многие ко многим - belongsToMany)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Записываете полученные данные в переменную, например:

```
$attributes = ['value' => $request->value];
```

Затем обновляете промежуточную таблицу:

```
Item::find($item_id)->options()->updateExistingPivot($option_id, $attributes);
```

Проверьте, чтобы была объявлена связь многие-ко-многим с промежуточными данными:

```
// App\Item
public function options()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Option')->withPivot('sort','value');
}
```